# how to override style in css module?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

here is an example:

Component.module.css

```
.container {...}
.content {...}
```

Component.tsx

```
import style from './Component.module.css'
function Component() {
  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
      <div className={style.content}></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

App.tsx

```
import Component from './Component'
import style from './App.module.css'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className={style.app}>
      <Component/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

App.module.css

```
.app{
   // how to override .content
}
```

how to override `.content` in App.module.css?

Comment: Is there any other way besides passing in class?

Comment: Can you not use .app .content {} in app.module.css?

Comment: No, because in css module the class name will be transformed, 
e.g.  .app-->.App-module__app--hash_5 .content-->.Component-module__content--hash_5,
If written as .app .content {}, this will convert to .App-module__app--hash_5 .App-module__content--hash_5 {}

Comment: I must ask, why are you using modules for css? why not using styled-components instead?

Comment: anyway, im pretty sure that you give a class to an element, which means u will have to create another element with another class and use it instead of the first one. condition between the two. or you can use a condition to decide which class will be used when (pretty messy I guess but I couldn't find another way)